# execute a ubuntu program on a local windows computer

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04

I am accessing and using Ubuntu programs via ssh on windows computer. I have data on my windows computer. Is there any way I can execute Ubuntu program on the data that is present on my local windows machine.

Comment: The simplest option is to share the Windows data directory with the Ubuntu machine: you will need to install `samba` on Ubuntu. Another option is to run Ubuntu in a VM on Windows. I haven't experimented yet with integrated Ubuntu on Win10, but this may be worth investigating.

Comment: Thank you a lot. I will give it a try and keep you update.

Answer (score 0):

**Cygwin** is a collection of tools that offer a Linux-like environment on Windows.
Using Cygwin you can use apps from the *command prompt* as you can in the *terminal*(in Linux).

You have to download the source of the app or use your own version of the source, the compile it and then run it using **Cygwin**